How to make xr and standalone work together?
I like to use standalone document to separate my figures (or others) in dedicated files that are compiled once (or recompiled automatically if modified) then include in my main document.
But for some of my standalone files I need to use references (to floats or bib entries) from the main document.
For that purpose I found the xr package is well adapted.
Here comes my problem: if I compile the standalone by itself, the references are printed, but if the compilation is triggered by the main doc, then the references do not appear.
Here is a MWE:
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
   \section*{Main (External) Document}
   Main document with many citations \cite{Chomsky1957, Chomsky1965, Knuth1984texbook}.

   \section*{Imported Document from Same Directory}
   \includestandalone[mode=build]{./supp}%.tex

   \bibliography{ref}
\end{document} 

% supplementary.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xr} 
\externaldocument{./main} %

\begin{document}
   If I compile the file alone, citation works ; but with the compilation triggered by the main doc it won't \cite{Knuth1984texbook}.
\end{document}

% ref.bib
@book{Knuth1984texbook,
    Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
    Title = {The \TeX book, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
    Publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    Year = {1984},
}
@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957},
}
@book{Chomsky1965,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    Year = {1965},
}


Looking in the supp.log generated by the main file compilation, I found surprising that Package xr Info: IMPORTING LABELS FROM ./main.aux on input line 5. so the problem is not coming from label detection.
How could I make xr and standalone work together ?

that can not work. You are compiling the supp file while the main.aux is open for writing from the compilation of the main file. That means the content of the main.aux is in an unknown state depending on what is already written and what is in the buffer.

it would be much easier not to use standalone but to \input the tex source and handle labels naturally. standalone is essentially making a pdf and includng that and that loses all pdf annotations, that said it should probably work if you process supp first to get a pdf then main with pdflatex and bibtex and pdftex again then process supp again to get an correct pdf with the citations then pdftex main again to include the new su[pp

@UlrikeFischer So there is no way for you to use the main.aux from the last compilation (or a copy) that would be in a frozen state ?

@DavidCarlisle Indeed, using \input instead of \includestandalone will work. But when my standalone are large figures it takes a lot of time to compile things that are not changing at some point. Therefore I use \includestandalone to reduce this unnecessary compilation time.

but you could use \input and externalise the images without using xr, provided you don't need to compile the included image separately for some other reason. I'd use memoize and do it that way. (just don't try to use it if the class is standalone - the package is fine.)

well you could make first a copy of main.aux e.g. in the preamble and use that in the standalone file.

@UlrikeFischer Do you think you could propose a solution based on that ?

@cfr Humm, I don't know memoize. It seems cool but complex, so I need to meditate over it.

it is potentially complex but, in practice, it is often simpler than using, say, external. the real catch is that you really want perl installed, which may be a significant requirement if you use miktex on windows, and you probably need to install one or two perl modules regardless. (or python, but perl is default because more people have that --- texlive supplies perl on windows.) if you get that far, just loading memoize is often enough, but it depends on the details of what you're doing, obviously.
